# How to include an external resource to WorkingSet in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, working-set

I'm developing an Eclipse Plug-in that is working with custom working sets. Those working sets can contain projects from the workspace but also external projects which are selected by the user through a wizard.

After selecting a folder, my plugin returns a `java.io.File` with the path of the folder. Now I'd like to add this folder as a resource to my custom working set. Right now adding elements to working-sets works by adding instances of `IAdaptable` to a `List<IAdaptable>`, which is then given to the `IWorkingSetManager`, so casting/converting the `File` to something like `IResource` or `IFolder` should work. So my question is, how do I make my `java.io.File` `IAdaptable`?

Comment: Since you can't modify java.io.FIle you cannot make it implement IAdaptable.

Comment: It does not have to be a java.io.File! I just need to add an external resource folder to my working set and the only thing I have is the path to the resource.

Comment: `IAdaptable` is just a normal interface - make something that implements it.

Comment: Yes, I did that, but now I need an Adapter to adapt my file type to be viewer as a resource in the project explorer, right? I've found examples with properties implementing IPropertySource, but I'm not sure how to adapt an external resource.

Comment: Resources must be in the workspace, Project Explorer will not show things outside of the workspace. You might be able to do something with IFile.createLink to create a link in the workspace to an external resource.